# How to change the keyboard layout console-only

Tags: keyboard, setup, terminal, locale

How can I change the keyboard layout from default (GB? US?) to anything else?
I tried various methods from posts related to debian but these fail. Installing and executing `raspi-config` does not help.

Answer (score 2):

After having installed `raspi-config` I also had to install

`keyboard-setup`
`console-data`
`console-setup`

Running `raspi-config` afterwards and changing locale settings worked like a charm!
See also [github](https://github.com/openhab/openhabian/issues/75)

Answer (score 0):

`raspi-config` should work out of the box.  But it is interactive, and you have to have to run it from the console via a keyboard or it won't show the keyboard menu.  (I guess the idea is that if you're not using the keyboard, you don't need to change the keyboard).

But you can edit the file `/etc/default/keyboard`.  As an example, I just change XKBLAYOUT from "gb" to "us".  Then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive keyboard-configuration`.  Once done, you'll probably need to reboot for it to take effect.